# Checksum for keeping the integrity of the timestamp

Tags: java, date, checksum

I have timestamp which is basically "ddMMYYHHMMss". what i want to do is everytime i run the program the seconds value change but my checksum remains the same. can anyone help me with this. i want the checksum should change everytime the seconds(time) changes.

```
public class Checksum {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File f = new File("D:/test.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
    if(!f.exists()){
        f.createNewFile();
    }
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMYYHHmmss");
    String formatteddate = sd.format(d);
    System.out.println(formatteddate);
    pw.println(formatteddate);
    pw.close();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String line = null;

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        break;
    }
    br.close();

    System.out.println("MD5    : " + toHex(Hash.MD5.checksum(line)));
    System.out.println("SHA1   : " + toHex(Hash.SHA1.checksum(line)));
    System.out.println("SHA256 : " + toHex(Hash.SHA256.checksum(line)));
    System.out.println("SHA512 : " + toHex(Hash.SHA512.checksum(line)));
}
 private static String toHex(byte[] bytes) {
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes);
    }
}

class CheckSumGenerator {
public enum Hash {

    MD5("MD5"), SHA1("SHA1"), SHA256("SHA-256"), SHA512("SHA-512");

    private String name;

    Hash(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public byte[] checksum(String input) {
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(getName());
            byte[] block = new byte[4096];
            int length;
            if (input.length()> 0) {
                digest.update(block, 0, input.length());
            }
            return digest.digest();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Have a think about what the value of line is when you come out of the while loop, that will tell you why the checksum is always the same.

Comment: I checked the value its properly reflecting the change in time, but still checksum is same.

Comment: What's the value of 'line' after the break? To be more precise: Between br.close(); and your first System.out.?

Comment: first run :before writing on file :23042018180825
while reading from file:23042018180825
MD5    : 36DF9540A5EF4996A9737657E4A8929C
SHA1   : 4595C5B7AC9F265CDF89ACEC0069630697680F96
SHA256 : E7ECEBBC590BC88B3761FA6CD03D749F87463DABB67021A5C6768C25EC68B3F2
SHA512 : 7CF95CDE6D8D85F13497DDBABC60A56BCA0ABEABD2BC3E723C0A4A8C0784B14C4EE3317620B79D260D42608C8B907571499187078D14304A5E7A84BC55193CE9

Comment: second run:   before writing on file :23042018180920
while reading from file:23042018180920
MD5    : 36DF9540A5EF4996A9737657E4A8929C
SHA1   : 4595C5B7AC9F265CDF89ACEC0069630697680F96
SHA256 : E7ECEBBC590BC88B3761FA6CD03D749F87463DABB67021A5C6768C25EC68B3F2
SHA512 : 7CF95CDE6D8D85F13497DDBABC60A56BCA0ABEABD2BC3E723C0A4A8C0784B14C4EE3317620B79D260D42608C8B907571499187078D14304A5E7A84BC55193CE9

Comment: as you can see in both run the time stamp is different "23042018180825 " and "23042018180920 " but the checksum is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually pass your `input` into the `digest.update(...)` call. You always pass the same empty byte array: `block = new byte[4096];` Therefore it will always return the same